# Is there a way to prune Travis's list of branches?

Tags: github, travis-ci

Travis has records for a lot of old feature branches, etc. that no longer exist in the corresponding GitHub repository, but they clutter the output of `travis branches`. Is there a way to prune Travis's list of branches, or at least the ones displayed by the CLI?

Comment: Would clearing cache (http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/caching/#Clearing-Caches) help?

Answer (score 16):

Sadly there is no way to do that right now. :(

[Here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2614) is a link to the Travis issue on it.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to come out as harsh, I meant my response to come out as pointing out a shortcoming in a tool that is on it's way to being fixed. I also added a link to the travis issue on this.

Comment: Note to viewers: Don't let the "Closed" mark on that issue confuse you. The actual issue is tracked in https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2614

Comment: Unfortunately, the Travis team locked the issue to prevent further comments or +1s, and haven't responded in nearly a year.

Comment: a few years now... how is this still an issue in an otherwise sweet  gizmo?